SAP Analytics Cloud OData Export Service - Deletes in Fact
Does anyone know if SAC OData Data Export Service capture Deleted records in Fact table.
The documentation says it is captured but I do not see it in postman.
When records are deleted in SAC, is there a soft delete that doesnt show up in export service.
Any input is appreciated.
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ANALYTICS_CLOUD/14cac91febef464dbb1efce20e3f1613/b01ea81ba3864bc0aa8fa384fb09eccc.html
